# Останавливает ли намертво QEventLoop поток выполнения операционной системы?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, асинхронность

Предположим, что мне нужно выполнять чтение данных из файла с некоторым интервалом времени, **не используя QFileSystemWatcher с сигналами** для мониторинга размера и тд. В интернете наткнулся на [подобное](https://rsdn.org/forum/cpp.qt/3513739.all#3514444) ожидание

```
QEventLoop eventLoop;
QObject::connect(m_webView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));

QTimer timer;
QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));
timer.setSingleShot(true);
timer.start(defaultTimeout);

eventLoop.exec();
```

Скажите пожалуйста, на сколько рационально подобное решение расходует ресурсы операционной системы? Что именно будет делать объект loop, пока его не остановит таймер? Не эквивалентно по КПД ли это голому `Sleep(1000)`, если выполнить в новом потоке, унаследовавшись от [QRunnable](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html#example-1-using-the-thread-pool)? Не будет ли лучше просто выполнять проверку с интервалом, используя `QTimer`?

Comment: Если интервал для выполнения задачи фиксированный, то самое очевидное  решение - использовать `QTimer::timeout()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, использование QEventLoop не "освобождает" QThread. Как следствие - его применение для реализации ожидания не решает проблему исчерпания свободных потоков у QThreadPool. Кроме того, так как использование DirectConnection у QObject::connect() в приоритете, не следует ждать высокой эффективности подобной реализации ожидания.

Ниже приведен код, применяющий QEventLoop по назначению. По умолчанию, после перемещения в новый поток, наследник QObject будет использовать в приоритете QEventLoop из актуального потока для обработки событий.

```
class Engine : public QThread {
  Q_OBJECT
  private:
    QThread* initialThread;
  public:
    explicit Engine() : QThread(nullptr){
        qDebug() << "Engine ctor thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
        this->initialThread = QThread::currentThread();
        moveToThread(this);
    }
    virtual ~Engine(){
        qDebug() << "Engine dtor";
    }
  protected:
    virtual void run(){
        qDebug() << "Engine run: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
        QEventLoop loop;

        qDebug() << "Engine before process";
        loop.processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
        qDebug() << "Engine after process";

        moveToThread(this->initialThread);
        emit done();
    }
    virtual bool event(QEvent *event){
        qDebug()
            << "event: "  << event->type()
            << "thread: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
        return true;
    }
  signals:
    void done();
};

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Engine e;
    e.start();
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(&e,new QEvent(QEvent::Type::MaxUser));
    QObject::connect(&e, SIGNAL(done()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

При этом консольный вывод будет следующий. Как видно - QEventLoop действительно дал нам возможность получить момент опустошения очереди событий. Это очень полезно при постраении асинхронных систем реального времени (например, JavaScript интерпретатор).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате выполнения данного отрезка кода приложение будет корректно завершено после выполнения произвольного множества событий, поставленного в очередь. В процессе обработки событий в QObject::event() мы так же можем ставить события в очередь, оттягивая момент завершения.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите усыпить поток, то лучше как-то так:
`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));`

Comment: В этом-то и дело: поток не должен спать, поток должен работать! QEventLoop предлагает прикладному программисту тот же функционал, что Async/Await в C#?

Comment: Тогда, вероятно, Вам нужно что-то вроде: `std::promise`, `std::future`, [туть](https://thispointer.com//c11-multithreading-part-8-stdfuture-stdpromise-and-returning-values-from-thread/)